# Programmatically getting an article from WikiPedia in .NET

Tags: c#, wikipedia, wikimedia, linq-to-wiki

I need to programmatically get articles from wikipedia, I need to be able to get sections and their content in form of HTML or raw text.

Take this page as an example: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/LINQ

I found this .NET Api, but it doesn't seem to support getting articles.

https://github.com/svick/LINQ-to-Wiki

Are there any .NET libraries that I can use, or will I have to parse the html contents of the website?

P.S. I know that wikipedia has an API but I can't see any examples of how to use it to do what I need.

Comment: Asking for libraries and other offsite resources is [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Try describing what problem you are having with your implementation.

Comment: Why don't you just use the HTML Agility Pack?

Answer (score 6):

The way to get article text using the API would be something like:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=LINQ&prop=revisions&rvprop=content

Using LINQ to Wiki, it's similar:

```
string text =
    wiki.CreateTitlesSource("LINQ")
        .Select(p => p.revisions().FirstOrDefault().value)
        .ToEnumerable()
        .Single();
```

For such a common operation, that's quite complicated code. I was thinking about adding helper methods for common operations like this one, but I didn't get to that yet.

Comment: That's interesting! Is there a way to get the article as html? *I'm programming for a mobile device*

Comment: Yeah, you can. In the URL, just add `&rvparse`. In LINQ to Wiki, use `.Select(p => p.revisions().Where(r => r.parse).FirstOrDefault().value)`.

Comment: Is there a means by doing a 'fromDate' on the url you provided @svick, so that you only retrieve articles from a specific date? Also is there a search function so that it brings back all articles based on a specific search word?

Comment: @Ebikeneser Yes, [you can use the search API module](https://github.com/svick/LINQ-to-Wiki/blob/4d66729902ed15097aff41f643a3add0960d3f87/LinqToWiki.Samples/Program.cs#L661). I don't understand what exactly do you mean by “articles from a specific date”.

Comment: Excellent, so say I wanted to search for 'Ronaldo' but I didnt want all results, just articles from say a week ago?

Answer (score 4):

You could do this a couple of ways:

Using [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and parse the html.  From the looks of that page all sections seem to be in the format

```
<div class="section">
```

Also from what I can glance from the `LINQ to Wiki` api, you can get page data by categories (which I believe is the sections you refer too).  Further analysis would be needed but I suggest you look into:

- [PageData](https://github.com/svick/LINQ-to-Wiki/blob/master/LinqToWiki.Core/Internals/PageData.cs)
- [NamespaceInfo](https://github.com/svick/LINQ-to-Wiki/blob/master/LinqToWiki.Core/Internals/NamespaceInfo.cs)